# How to convert all .wav files in subdirectories to .aac using neroAacEnc?

Tags: bash, shell-script, arch-linux

I have a collection of music in .wav format, and would like to convert it to .aac/.mp4 using neroAacEnc.

How do I do this?
I am using Arch Linux x86_64 and Xterm.

Comment: Are you open to using tools other than neroAacEnc?

Comment: So long as it equals it, yes. I only picked this because the quality was apparently very good.

Comment: Are you using `bash` or `Xterm`?  Did you mean to include the `bash` tag?

Comment: I can use either, I though that Xterm was a GUI for bash, but I appear to be wrong. Thank you for the information!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a quick one-liner that you can type in a terminal:

```
find . -name "*.wav" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do neroAacEnc -2pass -q 1 -if "$file" -of "${file%wav}m4a"; done
```

You can also use ffmpeg, as @slm suggests,

```
find . -name "*.wav" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -c:a libfdk_aac -vbr 3 output.m4a "${file%wav}m4a"; done
```

I'm not sure how neroAacEnc compares to ffmpeg, but I know ffmpeg is advanced quite popular with many Linux users.

---

**Explanation**

`find` is a program that returns paths to files that match a certain file property, in this case the file's name.  If all you wanted to know was what .wav files are in subdirectories of your current path, you would do `find . -name "*.wav"`.  Normally this outputs each file on a new line.  The `-print0` makes it separate the matches with a null character instead.  This allows for proper handling of filenames with spaces when we pass the output to the next commands.

The `|` character is known as a pipe.  It tells the shell to take the output of the command on the left and pass it as the input to the command on the right, in this case, the `read` command within the `while` loop.

The `read` command is used to take the output of `find` and assign it to a variable, "file".  Normally this would assign values to "file" each word at a time, but the `-d $'\0'$` causes the assignments to be delimited by the null character (matching how we delimited the files in `find` by using the `-print0` flag).

The while loops causes `read` to iteratively assign values to "file" for each matching filename.  The `do` and `done` are part of the standard bash syntax for a while loop:

```
while <something is true>; do
    <run some commands>
done
```

In this case, our "run some command" is either `ffmpeg` or `neroAacEnc`.  In each of the cases, the input file (i.e., `$file`) is specified with the "file" variable that we assigned with `read`, and the output file (i.e., `${file%wav}w4a`) is a manipulation of this variable that allows us to specify a different name for the output.  Normally `$file` or `${file}` would evaluate to the name of the file, say *some song.wav*.  The `%` says to cut off from the right of the variable any sequence matching the characters[1] to the right of the `%` (i.e., "wav").  So `${file%wav}` would evaluate to *some song.*, and then the "m4a" is there to be the new end of the filename: *some song.m4a*.

---

[1] I say "characters" here for simplicity.  The sequence to the right of the `%` could be a regular expression.  For example, if we said `${file%w*v}` and the variable was *some song.w1234v*, it would also evaluate to *some song.*.

Comment: I tried this, but I get a lot of errors. It seems that the file name is getting split up into separate inputs (the filename has spaces in it). How can I fix this?

Comment: Right, I forgot to add quotes around $file to handle spaces in file names.  I've updated the commands, try again.

Comment: I had to omit -2pass (it turns out it only works with a certain set of other settings, but omitting that this works great. Thank you! If you could explain why/what is going on here that would be even better, but if you don't have time I appreciate it regardless.

Comment: For the record, fdk_aac and neroAacEnc are both considered to be good AAC encoders, while all the other AAC encoders in ffmpeg are... not. Also, fdk_aac cannot be legally distributed with ffmpeg in binary form due to licensing issues, so to use it you would have to compile your own ffmpeg.

Comment: Thanks for the update :) Now have a much better understanding of the find command!

Comment: `ffmpeg` replaced with `avconv` http://askubuntu.com/questions/432542/is-ffmpeg-missing-from-the-official-repositories-in-14-04

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the command line switches to neroAacEnc but something like this:

```
% cd <dir where .wav files are>
% find . -type f -name '*.wav' -exec sh -c '
orgfile="$0"
newfile="$(echo "$0" | sed 's/.wav/.aac/')"
neroAacEnc $orgfile $newfile
' {} \;
```

Or you could use ffmpeg to do the conversion (untested):

```
% cd <dir where .wav files are>
% find . -type f -name '*.wav' -exec sh -c '
orgfile="$0"
newfile="$(echo "$0" | sed 's/.wav/.aac/')"
ffmpeg -i $orgfile -ab 256 $newfile
' {} \;
```

#### As a script (put the below into a file)

```
#!/bin/bash

# myscript.bash
cd <dir where .wav files are>

find . -type f -name '*.wav' -exec sh -c '
orgfile="$0"
newfile="$(echo "$0" | sed 's/.wav/.aac/')"

neroAacEnc -2pass -q 1 -if $orgfile -of $newfile
' {} \;
```

After making the file (myscript.bash) make it executable `chmod +x myscript.bash`, run it `./myscript.bash`, and you're done.

#### References

-[FFmpeg and AAC Encoding Guide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/AACEncodingGuide)

**NOTE:** There are additional "recipes" for converting .wav to .aac and getting different qualities, characteristics, etc.

Comment: It would be called like this:
neroAacEnc -2pass -q 1 -if <input_file> -of <output_file>

Comment: Also, is this a file (like an executable> or do I type all this in at once? I'm pretty new to linux in terms of knowledge.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but get an error:
"No output file specified"

Comment: Can you run the script you created like this: `bash -x myscript.bash > debug.log 2>&1` and post the contents of debug.log to http://pastebin.com/ please.

Answer (score 2):

I'd also use ffmpeg. If you use libfaac, it only supports -aq and not -vbr or -ab:

```
for f in **/*.wav; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -c:a libfaac -aq 150 "${f%wav}m4a"; done
```

`**` requires bash 4.0 or higher and `shopt -s globstar` or zsh. You can show information about the result files with `ffmpeg -i`.

According to http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/AACEncodingGuide, the native encoder (which was used if I didn't specify -c:a) is lower quality than libfaac, which is lower quality than libfdk_aac. `--enable-libfdk_aac --enable-nonfree` (or `brew install ffmpeg --with-fdk-aac`) includes support for libfdk_aac.

If you have 4 CPUs, this runs up to 4 processes in parallel:

```
find . -name \*.wav | parallel ffmpeg -i {} -c:a libfdk_aac -vbr 4.5 {.}.m4a
```

-vbr 0 is lowest, -vbr 5 is highest.

Comment: +1 for the parallel processing, I have a quad core with hyper threading so this saves a lot of time!