# Why doesn't this find command work? Regex & Find variants for .mp3 .wav and .m4a files

Tags: find, regular-expression, wildcards

```
2015.10.25 Move on and Be Blessed.wav             dummy.m4a
2015.11.17 BS Full.wav.mp3                        
2015.11.17 BS MOL.wav.mp3           

find . -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.wav' -o -name '*.m4a' -print0
```

but this command works
`find . -name "*.wav" -o -name '*.mp3' -print0`

I've been reading
[How to use find command to search for multiple extensions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/how-to-use-find-command-to-search-for-multiple-extensions) and
[How to convert all .wav files in subdirectories to .aac using neroAacEnc?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73204/how-to-convert-all-wav-files-in-subdirectories-to-aac-using-neroaacenc)

How come my regex version does not work?
`find . -regex '*\.\(.mp3\|.wav\|.m4a\)' -print0`
Could I pipe this regex command into the subsequent command outlined in the second referenced post, `find . -name "*.wav" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -c:a libfdk_aac -vbr 3 output.m4a "${file%wav}m4a"; done` replacing the `find . -name "*.wav" -print0` command?

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to be missing its beginning, but the reason your find-regex command does not work is that you need to start with `.*` (regex syntax for "anything") not just `*` (glob syntax for "anything"). You also have an extraneous `.` in front of your extensions.

```
find . -regex '.*\.\(mp3\|wav\|m4a\)' -print0
```

As for your pipe, it should work. Test it by putting an `echo` in front of `ffmpeg`. My instinct would be to write a function or a script that I could test on one file, or else make sure that my files do not have newlines in them. Spaces are one thing, users like them, but newlines are a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex doesn't work, because that's not a valid regex.

`*` doesn't work anything like the same in a regex. To get roughly the same behaviour, your need `.*` but typically you don't need anything, because a regex is a substring match anyway.

You also need to escape any `.` you mean to match a literal - because otherwise it means any character. Because you've escaped the first `.` and not the second, you're *actually* matching.

```
.?mp3
```

Which I don't think you're likely to have.

So:

```
find -regex '\.(mp3|wav|m4a)$'
```

Would probably do the trick.

I'm not sure why your first pattern doesn't work, because I'm not on a Unix system at the moment to double check. But I would guess it'll be because the `-print0` is being applied to the last term, not all of them. By any chance you your first example -are any `wav` files being printed?

Because you might be needing brackets:

```
find \( -name '*.wav' -o -name '*.mp3' -o -name '*.m4a' \) -print0
```

Comment: You were 39 seconds earlier :)

Comment: what's the significance of the `$` sign syntax?

Comment: End of line. So won't match `file.mp3.bak`

Comment: @phillipsk the `$'\0'` conveys a bare ASCII NUL to the -d option. I had never seen that before, but it works and `'\0'` does not.

Comment: @Sobrique the find regex match is a match on the whole name, not just a substring. It is as if ^ and $ are implied at beginning and end.